# Spring Boot JPA avoid duplicates results when returning as JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa

Hi I have a spring boot project which uses Spring Data JPA. I have written a custom JPQL statement where I return multiple rows of data where only a single value is the difference among them. I have an @ManytoMany relationship with an entity called type where I am only fetching the tag column in that entity to avoid lazy exception.

Club.Java class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Club {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String shortName;

    @Column(length = 80)
    private String description;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String email;

    private boolean status;

    @Lob
    private Blob logo;

    @Lob
    private Blob cover;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String website;

    private double longitude;

    private double latitude;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String registrationId;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date registrationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastActiveDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club")
    private List<Favourite> favourites;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Type> type = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Address address;

}
```

Type.java class where the tag column lies on.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String tag;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private List<User> user;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private List<Club> club;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdDate;

}
```

ClubRepository.java

```
@Query("SELECT new com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.name, c.shortName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, a, t.tag) FROM Club c JOIN c.type t JOIN c.address a")
    List<ClubSend> findAllClubs();
```

So in essence my query returns duplicate data for club and its all attributes where the only different data in that row is a tag. How can I avoid this? I rather return the tags as an array. @ElementCollection is not an option as I am using Type as an entity and I am using the same entity in one of my other class as well which is user.

The Result:

```
[
{
        "name": "Manchester City",
        "shortName": "MC",
        "description": "Swiss Soccer Club",
        "email": "soccer@gmail.com",
        "logo": null,
        "cover": null,
        "longitude": 79.8766,
        "latitude": 6.858,
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "address1": "Bay Street",
            "address2": "Yorkshire",
            "postalCode": "100",
            "city": "Auckland",
            "country": "Newzeland",
            "createdDate": "2020-12-08"
        },
        "tag": "Soccer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Manchester City",
        "shortName": "MC",
        "description": "Swiss Soccer Club",
        "email": "soccer@gmail.com",
        "logo": null,
        "cover": null,
        "longitude": 79.8766,
        "latitude": 6.858,
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "address1": "Bay Street",
            "address2": "Yorkshire",
            "postalCode": "100",
            "city": "Auckland",
            "country": "Newzeland",
            "createdDate": "2020-12-08"
        },
        "tag": "Cricket"
    }]
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? It is a bit ambigious

Comment: if you check the JSON name, shortName and other attributes are repeating I just want to return a single club entity with tags array. But the way I have written the custom query I am unable to do so.

Comment: If you want to return a single Entity then change your query and Method in your repo.
`@Query("SELECT new com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.name, c.shortName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, a, t.tag) FROM Club c JOIN c.type t JOIN c.address a WHERE c.id = ?1")
    ClubSend findOneClub(int clubId);`

Comment: Of course, I want all clubs to return, not just one single club. But in here the relationship is one club contains multiple tags, like in my instance it's different sports. I want to fetch all the clubs but in a club, I want to return all club related details and the multiple tags it has as a single object. e.g, "tag": ["cricket", "football", "swimming"] but rather I am duplicating all club related data in the JSON and the only different data item i am returning from the JSON is that tag. I hope I am clear this time.